# Is it possible to sort and remove duplicate like this in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I used a formula =SORTBY(F6:G11,UNIQUE(G6:G11)) then it gives an #value error but the formula which I used as shown in the picture is unable to give me my desire

[image]

Comment: I think what you want is `=UNIQUE(SORTBY(H6:H10,G6:G10))`

Comment: still not working b and 3 are not removed.

Comment: [Works for me](https://imgur.com/a/wUbxklu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},XLOOKUP(B1:B6,B1:B6,A1:A6,,0),B1:B6))
```

Comment: It works. I have another question if we want to display the value of columns A and B of another workbook sheet we put this in column A ='[workbookname.xlsx]sheetname'!$A:$A   is there another way to do this because every time we have to change the sheet name.  Is it possible that we write sheet names in a cell for example in cell D and the values appear in Columns A and B?